# create-react-app with express server not rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, express, internet-explorer, create-react-app

My app works great with Chrome and Safari. It's a react app with an express backend. When I open it in IE it renders a white page and I get this error:

[image]

Ive tried looking up the error and I could find a solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method [isn't supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility). You'll need a polyfill to make it work in IE. [You can check Mozilla for a working polyfill.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Where you place the polyfill depends on how your app looks like. The only thing that's important is that it's loaded before your other scripts. You can put in a JS file and load it before your other JS files.

```
<script>
... Polyfill script
</script>

<script src="react-app.js"></script>
```

Since your building a React application I assume you're using some kind of bundler, eg webpack. Then a good practice would be to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code to ES5 (which all major browsers can handle). Babel will also a lot of other features and benefits. I propose that you read more about that.

Comment: Where exactly should this go? or when Where I add the working polypill function ?